# 3ds max like UV relax

Tags: uv

Does blender have a UV relax like 3ds max: so it relaxes the entire UV island with the border vertices including ( Minimize stretch doesn't effect the border vertices)?

Comment: Maybe you could include a reference image of before and after?

Comment: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?294904-AddOn-smooth-selected-uv

Answer (score 4):

In 3dsMax the *Relax Tool* has multiple options to relax the UV mesh: By Face angles, Edge angles and by Centers. And it can also relax the island borders.

Blender lacks these features, and it's relaxation (*"Minimize stretch"*) usually makes things worse (because the border doesn't relax so the stretching from border propagates inside).

Instead what is used in Blender is UV Sculpting (UV > UV Sculpt <kbd>Q</kbd>). This brings up a brush with additional options in *Tool Shelf* panel <kbd>T</kbd>:

[image]

The default *Grab* brush can be switched to *Smooth* brush with *HC* and *Laplacian* smooth methods. Also *Lock Borders* can be turned off to smooth the island borders.

Note that both the smoothing algorithms are not real UV relaxation. They work spatially, not angle-based. The difference is that *HC* preserves the shape of islands better. After sculpting you should still run *Minimize Stretch* for best results, that's why it is in blender.

It takes a bit more work but you can get same stretch-less UV map as in Max.